# How to make a string that only includes spaces be an invalid input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie in coding using python and I'm trying to write a piece of small code that prints whatever you input in the terminal, but I don't want anything that only includes spaces and no other characters or doesn't even have an input to be printed. Here's the code:

```
while True:

    my_name= input("> ")
    if "" in my_name:
        print("I don't know what that means. Please choose a valid answer.")
    else:
        print(f"Ah, I see, so your name is {my_name}?")
```

would love to have multiple solutions to this, and thank you if you helped :)

Comment: `if my_name.strip() == ""`

Comment: `if all(char==' ' for char in a)`

Comment: As you want multiple solutions: Overkilling it with a regular expression: `if re.match('^ *$', my_name)`

Comment: Please don't answer questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace

I think this should do the trick

```
if my_name.isspace():
    print("Your name is full of spaces")
```

Comment: and a side note, isspace() does not check for `None` and ''

Answer (score 0):

There's one way of doing that by using exceptional handling for no input using *try - except* block and a flag variable that checks if input doesn't contain only spaces.

```
try:
    flag = False
    my_name = input()
    for i in my_name:
        if i != ' ':
            flag = True
    if flag:
        print(my_name)
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
except:
    print('No input')
```

The other ways can be using the built in function strip() which removes the trailing and leading spaces in input.
If the input has only spaces then strip() will remove all of them resulting in an empty string.

```
try:
    my_name = input()
    if my_name.strip() == '':
        print('Invalid input')
    else:
        print(my_name)
except:
    print('No input')
```

Comment: i tried both ways you provided, but for some reason the except part never worked,  and the first method just printed 'Invalid input' no matter what input i gave. (just telling you, hope you aren't offended) EDIT: also for the second method even though except didn't work, when I didn't gave input it still provides Invalid input, so it's fine

Comment: It is working fine in my system.. Tho I figured out that the except part won't work on terminal but it works on online ide and custom input files. It can be resolved by using if statement.. `if my_name == ' ': print('no input')`

Answer (score 0):

Python isspace() method is used to check space in the string. It returns true if there are only white space characters in the string. Otherwise it returns false.
ex:

```
# Python isspace() method example  
# Variable declaration  
str = " " # empty string  
# Calling function  
str2 = str.isspace()  
# Displaying result  
print(str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, you can use `bool`s:

```
while True:
    my_name= input("> ")
    if my_name.strip():
        print(f"Ah, I see, so your name is {my_name}?")
    else:
        print("I don't know what that means. Please choose a valid answer.")
```